# I want position, but I get ncols and nrows of array

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, position

I'm a student, and I'm trying to get the last piece of code working on my assignment. This has been asked a million times, but I haven't been able to find a solution that works for me. I can only get the last position of the array to print when I run this program. I can't use any shortcuts (vectors, maxelement(), etc).  Can anyone help?

```
#define inputfile "C:\\C_txt_files\\wind.txt"

int i, j, nrows, ncols;
double wind_max, wind_min, wind_array[12][5], index_minmonth=0, 
       index_minyear=0, index_maxmonth=0, index_maxyear=0;

fscanf(wind, "%d %d", &nrows, &ncols);

/*Find Min and Max, and Compute average for each row. Locate Min and Max*/
wind_min = wind_array[0][0];
wind_max = wind_array[0][0];
for(i=0; i<nrows; i++)
{
for(j=0; j<ncols; j++)
{   
    if(wind_array[i][j]<wind_min)
       wind_min = wind_array[i][j];
       index_minmonth = i;
       index_minyear = j;
    if(wind_array[i][j]>wind_max)
       wind_max = wind_array[i][j];
       index_maxmonth = i;
       index_maxyear = j;      
}
}
index_minmonth += 1;
index_minyear += 1;
index_maxmonth += 1;
index_maxyear += 1;
printf("Minimum speed is %2.0f mph in month %2.0f, year %1.0f.\n", wind_min, 
      index_minmonth, index_minyear);
printf("Maximum speed is %2.0f mph in month %2.0f, year %1.0f.", wind_max, 
      index_maxmonth, index_maxyear);
```

This is what prints:
Minimum speed is  5 mph in month 12, year 5.
Maximum speed is 12 mph in month 12, year 5.

Comment: You need `{ }` for if-body.

Comment: fscanf(wind, "%d %d", &nrows, &ncols);I'm reading a file. I forgot to include this code.

Comment: The indentation for your `if` statements doesn't match the way the compiler reads the code.  Add braces around the body of the `if` statement.  C is *not* Python.

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialiaze the variables `nrows` and `ncols`. Otherwise you are working with garbage values.

Also you need to `{}` in loop body.

Otherwise it just changes its value every single time and you arrive at the last element's index.

*Later OP mentioned about reading from file. So initialization part not needed as it reads from file itself.

Comment: Thank you! That was what I was missing.

Comment: @drewsefer.: If this answer helped you can select my answer(the right mark beside answer) ..it would help future users.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the scope is wrong when you use "if".